# How to automatically generate csrf tokens in spring security / thymeleaf without using @EnableWebMvcSecurity

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, csrf, thymeleaf

I've been trying to figure out why the hidden csrf field is not automatically added to my login form.
I'm using Spring 4.1.1 with Spring Security 4.0.1 and Thymeleaf 2.1.4.

All I can find to fix the issue is to either use the _csrf variable in thymeleaf to add the field manually (although _csrf is null for me), or use @EnableWebMvcSecurity in Java config.
However, I am using xml to configure security and would like to keep it that way.
What it all boils down to is: What can I add to the security xml to make the thymeleaf generate the csrf token field?

My current configuration is:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <!-- **************************************************************** -->
    <!--  RESOURCE FOLDERS CONFIGURATION                                  -->
    <!--  Dispatcher configuration for serving static resources           -->
    <!-- **************************************************************** -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/dist/**" location="file:/var/www/meubelplan/dist/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="file:/var/www/meubelplan/css/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="file:/var/www/meubelplan/js/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="file:/var/www/meubelplan/images/"/>

    <!-- **************************************************************** -->
    <!--  SPRING ANNOTATION PROCESSING                                    -->
    <!-- **************************************************************** -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.wwk.meubelplan"/>

    <!-- **************************************************************** -->
    <!--  SPRING SECURITY                                                 -->
    <!-- **************************************************************** -->

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="sem" password="rtyfghvbn" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                <security:user name="winnie" password="ikbenwinnie" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <security:http pattern="/account/login" security="none"/>
    <security:http pattern="/account/logout" security="none"/>
    <security:http pattern="/account/create" security="none"/>
    <security:http use-expressions="false">
        <security:csrf/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern='/account/**' access='ROLE_USER' />
        <security:form-login login-page='/account/login' default-target-url='/account' always-use-default-target='true'/>
        <security:logout logout-url="/account/logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" logout-success-url="/account/login"/>
    </security:http>

    <!-- **************************************************************** -->
    <!--  THYMELEAF-SPECIFIC ARTIFACTS                                    -->
    <!--  TemplateResolver <- TemplateEngine <- ViewResolver              -->
    <!-- **************************************************************** -->

    <bean id="templateResolver"
          class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.FileTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/var/www/meubelplan/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
        <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="cacheable" value="false"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine"
          class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
        <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My thymeleaf template for the form is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:include="partials/general/head"></head>
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <nav th:replace="partials/general/navbar"></nav>

        <div th:replace="partials/general/logobar"></div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

                <br/><br/>

                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Login om uw account gegevens te bekijken</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form name="loginForm" method="POST" th:action="@{'~/account'}">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="username">Email address</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit">Inloggen</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div><!-- /.container -->

    <span th:replace="partials/general/scripts"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers in the right direction :)

Regards,

Sem

Comment: Could you try declaring a bean of the type `org.springframework.security.web.servlet.support.csrf.CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, although this didn't work initially, it did push me in the right direction. After some searching I came across this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21757222/spring-security-3-2-0-csrf-token-not-working-in-freemarker-template

Although the template engine is different, the issue is the same, and I got it to work with the solution to that question.

Comment: @semvdwal could you please share the solution. I have struggling to make it work. Thanks in advance

Comment: @RachitAgrawal I answered my question some time ago, see the second answer of this question, I've now also marked it so you can easily see which one it is. However, your case might be different, so if the solution provided doesn't help, feel free to provide me with some details so I can help you figure it out (hopefully). Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the information I needed in this other question:
[spring security 3.2.0 csrf token not working in freemarker template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21757222/spring-security-3-2-0-csrf-token-not-working-in-freemarker-template)

The answer is this:

Adding the following xml to your xml configuration will enable thymeleaf to automatically add the csrf token input to your forms.

security.xml

```
<bean id="requestDataValueProcessor" class="org.springframework.security.web.servlet.support.csrf.CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor"/>

<bean id="csrfFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository">
            <property name="headerName" value="X-SECURITY" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>csrfFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
  </filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>csrfFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

If it isn't automatically inserting a CSRF token you can force it through the folllowing line:

```
<input type="hidden"
    name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
    value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, I was looking to have thymeleaf generate the field automatically.

Comment: Thymeleaf automatically generates the parameter as it is. Can you check your generated html page source code and confirm whether there is a hidden input

Comment: Many years has passed. So is there a way for Thymealeaf to automatically generate csrf parameter, without us having to manually create input element for it.